# US J1 Visa - Two-Year Residency 212(e)

Tags: usa

If my passport is stamped with 212(e) - Two-Year Residency Requirement on the US J1 visa and I do not utilize the visa to visit the US, does the 2-year requirement still hold when I apply for H1B?

Answer (score 3):

The [text of 212(e)](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006/0-0-0-2364.html) says the restriction only applies to a person who has been “admitted” as a J1 (or who changed status to J1), so the 2-year requirement should not apply if you never used the visa and never changed status to J1. It would be a good idea to raise this point with your employer’s immigration attorney and to bring a copy of 212(e) to the visa interview in case it comes up.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please specify the source too?

Comment: @DhruvKuchhal I added a link to USCIS’s copy of the INA.